# What does pair done means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I asked someone to reduce the amount of content that he provided to be included in a website and he suggested he can pair done the information.

What does pair done mean?

Comment: What you heard was not *pair done* but *pare down*--that is, take "slices" off of it to make it smaller.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: OK possibly. He wrote pair done in the email. Maybe it's autocorrect. Your answer looks plausible. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The correct phrase is "pare down":

> [pare down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pare+down) — decrease gradually or bit by bit

It is commonly incorrectly written as "pair down".